# Fiddler extension development: only operate on requests from composer

Tags: fiddler

I'm trying to create a fiddler (v4.x) extension that builds and adds a custom header to requests generated by the composer. I started down the road of creating an IAutoTamper implementation that adds the header on the AutoTamperRequestBefore event. I quickly realized that this event fires for every request that passes through the fiddler proxy, not just for requests generated from the composer.

Is there any way to detect if a request was generated by the composer? Alternatively, is there a better extension point to handle this in other than through an AutoTamper?

Comment: Wireshark isn't an option due to organizational issues (approved tooling, accepted workflow, etc...).

Comment: In that case, I would contact the IT dept. and ask them which sniffers are approved.

Comment: I've already done that, hence the organizational constraints.

Comment: Wireshark doesn't tamper with requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you right-click on a session in the Web Sessions list, you can choose Properties to see all of the [Session Flags](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/dev/SessionFlags.asp) set on that session. You'll notice that all requests from the composer have a flag named **X-From-Builder**.

So, in your extension's code, you can simply write:

```
// Inside AutoTamperRequestAfter
if (oSession.oFlags.ContainsKey("X-From-Builder")) { 
  // Whatever...
}
```